# Audio tag won't play from URL in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, html5-audio

Below is the audio tag as loaded in IE and below that the results of the network tab.

```
<audio id="audio-alt" preload="auto" controls="controls">
    <source id="waveform-src" src="https://www.song.com/filename=tests.mp4" type="audio/mp4">
</audio>
```

[image]

Any idea why the type is application/json and/or why this request is aborted? This is an IE-only defect. Playing the same file from the same server works just fine in Chrome.

Comment: Have you configured the server to set the correct mime-type in the response header?

Comment: @K3N yes the header is set in the return method on the server to `Content-Type: audio/mp4`